# Fatal error call to undefined function mysqli_stat_bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the below php script

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect'.mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($con, "mysql");
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "Select * from bbau_login where username=? and password=?");
mysqli_stat_bind_param($statement, $username, $pasword);
mysqli_stat_execute($statement);
mysqli_stat_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stat_bind_result($statement, $id, $name, $username, $password);

$user = array();

while (mysqli_stat_fetch($statement)) {
    $user[name] = $name;
    $user[username] = $username;
    $user[password] = $password;
}
echo json_encode($user);
mysqli_stat_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
```

But every time I call this script I get the error as

> Fatal error call to undefined function mysqli_stat_bind_param()

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your `mysqli_stat_*` calls to `mysqli_stmt_*` calls.

You also should use quotes when using associative arrays:

```
$user['name'] = $name;
$user['username'] = $username;
$user['password'] = $password;
```

instead of

```
$user[name]=$name;
$user[username]=$username;
$user[password]=$password;
```